# Наложение текста на фотографию html

Tags: html

Я новичок в программировании, много чего не знаю, поэтому прошу помочь наложить текст на фотографию

```
<section class="section"> <div class="container"> <div class="background">
<img src="/4khd.github.io/images/background2.jpg"> </div> <div class="section_header" <h3 class="section_title">Choose a theme</h3> <div class="nav2"> <a class="nav2_link" href="#">Cars</a> <a class="nav2_link" href="#">Nature</a> <a class="nav2_link" href="#">Landscape</a> </div>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch) no-repeat center center / cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 8vw;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```